# Added eth0:0 configuration but fails on ifup with "RTNETLINK answers: file exists"

Tags: ubuntu, networking, eth0

I have an Ubuntu Server I'm adding some interfaces for and I can't figure out what I am be missing.

Here's my `/etc/network/interfaces/`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.100.60.54
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    network 10.100.0.0
    broadcast 10.100.255.255
    gateway 10.100.0.1

 iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 10.100.60.71
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    gateway 10.100.0.1
```

Then the following occurs:

```
sudo ifup eth0:0
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0:0.
```

Looked around for this issue and everyone seems to encounter it in different ways. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gateway` stanza creates a default route for the whole machine. The second stanza would create a second default route, and you get a `File exists` error.

This error means you'd have a second route for the prefix `0.0.0.0/0` -- that's what a default route is.

If you need further explanations about routing, please fell free to ask.